# Verify header before request receive in tomcat

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, http-headers

I need verify header before receive the request. I found that tomcat valve can help in it. I follow  these steps but valve is not called:

1. make a maven project and do this code in it.

   ```
   package cz.ValveTest;

   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.util.Enumeration;
   import java.util.logging.Level;
   import java.util.logging.Logger;

   import javax.servlet.ServletException;
   import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

   import org.apache.catalina.connector.Request;
   import org.apache.catalina.connector.Response;
   import org.apache.catalina.valves.ValveBase;

   public class ProcessingValve  extends ValveBase {

   private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ProcessingValve.class.getName());

   @Override
   public void invoke(Request request, Response response) throws IOException,
           ServletException {

   HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = request.getRequest();

    Enumeration<String> headerNames = httpServletRequest.getHeaderNames();
    logger.info("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");


    while (headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
            String header = headerNames.nextElement();
            logger.log(Level.INFO, "Header --> {0} Value --> {1}", new Object[]{header, httpServletRequest.getHeader(header)});
          }

     getNext().invoke(request, response);  


   }
   }
   ```
2. make jar and put jar inside tomcat/lib folder
3. add this line in server.xml

   ```
   <valve className="cz.ValveTest.ProcessingValve"/>
   ```
4. restart tomcat.
5. Now I hit my  web service with header:

   > Expect : 100-continue

but using this configuration and code valve is not called on http hit.If any one knew why tomcat valve is not called please help.

Comment: Where in the server.xml file did you put the `<valve>` element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tags in `server.xml` are **case sensitive**.

So try this :

```
<Valve className="cz.ValveTest.ProcessingValve"/>
```

Comment: Thanks now it is called on each http request