# How Can we call Http request inside tomcat Valve

Tags: apache, web-services, http, tomcat, header

I want to hit restfull api inside tomcat valve. I create tomcat valve successfully using this link [How to create tomcat valve ][1]

[1]: [Verify header before request receive in tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34236820/verify-header-before-request-receive-in-tomcat) .Now i want to authorized headers inside valve. In my application  There is restful web service for authorized token. I used spring rest template for hit webservice but when i restart tomcat when is show me error multivaluedmap class not found ,but same code run in simple java application.After this  I used Apache http client for hit rest web service (code is ok) . But when i restart tomcat there is again exception : **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/ClientProtocolException**

I simple want to authorized header inside tomcat valve so anyone can suggest to me how can i hit restfull api inside tomcat valve.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try with tomcat class loader .These Exception occur when these class not loaded. So you should load these class on runtime with the help tomcat class loader.

Answer (score 0):

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/http/client/ClientProtocolException

It means this class not found . You  should be  add  required jar files in tomcat.It is helpful for  loading the class on runtime.